# Yarn Terasort has the same execution time for 7 and 14 worker nodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have a hadoop cluster of 15 nodes ( 1 master & 14 slaves) with HDFS having a replication factor of 3. I have ran  TeraSort in YARN for 10GB with the following command:

```
yarn jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar terasort /terasort-input /terasort-output
```

After I have done it with 14 functional nodes I have started to decomission one node at a time and run TeraSort again to see how the time of execution changes. 
I have noticed that the time of execution does not actually change that much while I scale down and so I have similar execution times even at 7 slave nodes.

JobHistory recalls this values:

*14 slaves*: **Elapsed: 32mins, 12sec** ; Average Map Time: 4mins, 4sec; Average Shuffle Time: 14mins, 56sec;
Average Merge Time: 3mins, 50sec;
Average Reduce Time: 11mins, 35sec ;

*11 slaves*: **Elapsed: 30mins**, 6sec;
Average Map Time*:  5mins, 2sec;
Average Shuffle Time:   6mins, 9sec;
Average Merge Time:     8mins, 52sec;
Average Reduce Time:    11mins, 39sec;

*8 slaves*: **Elapsed:  32mins**, 15sec;
Average Map Time:   4mins, 29sec;
Average Shuffle Time:   13mins, 48sec;
Average Merge Time:     4mins, 20sec;
Average Reduce Time:    11mins, 11sec;

*7 slaves*: **Elapsed:  30mins, 6sec**;
Average Map Time:   4mins, 28sec;
Average Shuffle Time:   7mins, 26sec;
Average Merge Time:     8mins, 26sec;
Average Reduce Time: 11mins, 24sec;

Questions:

- Why do I almost have the same execution time for different number of
  worker nodes ?
- How can I take full advantage of the Hadoop cluster so that jobs run
  faster with 14 worker nodes than with 7 nodes?

Comment: Try looking into the possibilities of having multiple reducers

Answer (score 0):

1.Please run Terasort again with the larger data size.

2.Change the blocksize larger, e.g. 256M. How many reduce task do you set? if it is too small, set it larger.

Answer (score 0):

0) If you do not specify # of mappers & reducers ,then by default you have 2 mappers & 1 reduce. Use -D mapred.map.tasks -D mapred.reduce.tasks 
1) Dataset is too small, so that strange behavior occurs Results are very low 
2) Check  your IO. If you have 1 spinning disk per node it's not a good idea.